# Run Update Statement in Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am using C# with xamarin studio. I can't find a working example to do an update statement against my db. I am trying to update a value of a record from 50 to 100.

This class represents one record in db:

```
    [Table("record")]
    public class Record
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrementAttribute, Column("id")]
        public int ID {get; set;}
        [Column("value")]
        public string Value {get; set;}
    }
```

I can retrieve my records fine using:

```
    string pathToDatabase = "mydb.db";
    var db = new SqliteConnection (pathToDatabase);
    myRecords = db.Query<Record>("SELECT * FROM records;");
```

The update should be as simple as doing Get and then Update.

```
    var recToUpdate = db.Get<Record>(1); // record with primary key of 1.
    recToUpdate.Value = "100"; // instead of 50
    db.Update(recToUpdate);
```

It executes the update line fine, but the db still holds the older value of 50 instead of 100, when I run the app again.

Is my approach totally wrong?

Comment: Do you have your db located in a writable directory?  Or when you run your app multiple times, are you reseeding/recreating the database and deleting the copy that was modified in the prior run?

Comment: @Jason, I will check when I get home. I am not reseeding or deleting any db. The only code I have is what I wrote above.

Comment: Are you using a pre-existing db file?  If you are, you need to move it from the app bundle (which is read only) to a writable folder before you can update or modify it.

Comment: @Jason, thank you for the further comment. Yes, I am using an existing db file. It is located at the root directory. So if my inner-working code requires the update of an existing db, I should:
1. First move db somewhere else away from the app bundle 
2. Update DB
3. Bring DB back to app bundle?
Is it OK if the new folder which will house my db, be residing in the root?
Do you know of a tutorial for doing this!?

Comment: see my more detailed answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are including an existing db in your app bundle, you cannot write to it.  The app bundle is read only - this is an iOS security measure.  In order to write to your db, you will need to move it to a user writable folder.

```
// in your app startup
string rootPath = "/mydb.db";
string userPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "mydb.db";

// if userdb does not exist, copy it from the app bundle
if (!File.Exists(userPath)) {
  File.Copy(rootPath, userPath);
}
```

When you want to actually access your db, you just use the db access code you already have, but be sure you are using the user writable path.

```
var db = new SqliteConnection (userPath);
```

Finally, if your db is read-only and will not be updated by the user, you can leave it in the app bundle and don't need to make a writable copy.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
recToUpdate.Value = "100"; // instead of 50
int i =  db.Update(recToUpdate);
//check number of rows updated (i), db.Update() returns number of rows updated...
//or first try with recToUpdate.Value = 100; and see the number of rows affected + use try/catch if an error appears.
```

Comment: I made a mistake when writing my pseudo code. I am assigning the correct value to 'Value' (as a string), but I will try the try/catch and the the number of rows updated.